# HAProxy 1.4 - Don't log 2xx, only log 5xx

Tags: logging, configuration, load-balancing, haproxy

Good evening,

I'm using HAProxy (ver 1.4.24) as a load balancer for ~3000 requests per second. I am trying to log only 5xx responses, but I am unable to achive that. I am using the following configuration:

http://pastebin.com/TsTk9GQE

This configuration also logs 2xx requests, as long as 5xx and 4xx. I need only 5xx and 4xx, or just 5xx.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

There is an option called "dontlog-normal" in HAProxy to log only errors (whatever type of errors).

Just enable it in your defaults section.
Note in HAProxy 1.5, you have a new http-request set-log-level that you could use to disable logging when the status code is 2xx. This can simply be triggered by ACLs.

Baptiste