# Don't log 2xx in HAProxy on Openshift

Tags: logging, openshift, httpresponse, haproxy

I am trying to prevent logging 2xx responses from HAProxy on my Openshift Django server. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174291/haproxy-1-4-dont-log-2xx-only-log-5xx), but adding `option dontlog-normal` (and leaving the rest of the file as it was) in `haproxy/conf/haproxy.cfg` did not make a difference.

How can I stop 2xx response logging from HAProxy?

Comment: Did you restart haproxy after making the configuration change?

Comment: @corey112358 Yes, it restarts correctly but modifications to file don't impact how it works. Perhaps this config file is not the one read by haproxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not referring to the HAproxy log itself, rather to a HTTP server log. The HAproxy seem to do a health check every 2 seconds, which results in having these simple requests logged (but the HAproxy is originator, not the logger). You may want to check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23208789/vague-php-log-entry-in-openshift) (and the linked forum post) if you'd like to reduce the frequency of the checks.

In order not to log these completely, you would need to change the HTTP server logging configuration, which seems to be unavailable.